# Sharing an X Display between multiple users?

Tags: linux, display, xorg, x-server, multiple-users

If I have regular user one signed in to an X session through a display manager, is there anyway for regular user two to open a window of their own on the same display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about security, it's not too hard:

First, **X** needs to be running without the `-nolisten tcp` option that most display managers add by default.  How you change that can vary by display manager and distro.

User one can then open a terminal and run `xhost +host2`.  That allows all users on *host2* to open windows on user one's display.

User two on *host2* can then run:

```
export DISPLAY=host1:0
xterm
```

The `:0` part may have a different number. User one should check the value of their `DISPLAY` environment variable (by running `echo $DISPLAY`, for example).

If you want security, then you need to use [**xauth**](http://www.x.org/archive/current/doc/man/man1/xauth.1.html) to grant a magic cookie to user two so only they can open windows on your display (instead of all users on *host2*).

Comment: Perfect! xhost is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much for responding to my two month old question.